# overflow-x and overflow-y don't override overflow

Tags: css

I'm using bootstraptable and trying to make the cells show overflowed content but only down (i.e. overflow-y).
The thing is, the bootstraptable css uses overflow: hidden on all cells and setting overflow-y doesn't override it.

If I override overflow itself by doing

```
overflow: visible !important
```

it works but it overflows also horizontally which I don't want.
Doing:

```
overflow: auto !important;
overflow-x: hidden !important;
overflow-y: visible !important;
```

Also doesn't work.

Please help

Comment: If your overide doesn't work then the specificity of the css selector is too low. Can you show the full selector that is creating the current styling?

Comment: I can see it is being set in the browser dev console.

Answer (score 2):

The computed value of each `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` is dependent on the value of the other. As [described in spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow-properties):

> **Computed value**:   as specified, except with `visible`/`clip` computing to `auto`/`hidden` (respectively) if one of `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` is neither `visible` nor `clip`.

`visbile` and `clip` values only work on both directions at the same time.

Comment: So it's either hidden or visible on both of them?

Comment: Yes. But you can always use multiple wrappers and masks to work around it. If you provide a [mcve], I can provide a way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: I think my issue is with the specific component I'm using (react-select). If I use a regular html select, it pops fine over the cell. Check https://codesandbox.io/s/l45ww3k5y9

Answer (score -3):

```
overflow:hidden !important;overflow-y:auto !important;
```

This is enough to work.

Comment: Doing it like this does show scroll bars if I "open" the component inside the cell (it's a drop-down selection BTW), but that's not what I want. What I want is to be fully visible without scrollbars (really overflow the cell) which only happens if I set the overflow property itself to visible.